timm.utils.checkpoint_saver.CheckpointSaver save a best_model.pth.rar file, torch.load('./best_model.pth.rar') failure
I have a .pth.rar file which is the output file of timm.utils.checkpoint_saver.CheckpointSaver. I want to load the .pth.rar file as the model weights. So I torch.load this file
import torch
pth_file = './best_model.pth.rar'
torch.load(pth_file)

FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory:'./best_model.pth.rar'
Also, I unzip the .pth.rar file and try to load the .pkl file, failed either.
